# jQuery: animate addClass() - expand container?

Tags: javascript, jquery

following problem: I have a simple paragraph with a lot of text where I only want the first line to appear. So actually kind of a teaser. When clicking the first line the paragraph should animate to it's full height (and width). Right now I'm doing so by removing the class collpsed...

```
<p class="collapsed">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('p.collapsed').click(function() { 
   $(this).removeClass('collapsed').addClass('expanded');
   $(this).append("<a href='#' class='closer'>×</a>");
});

$('a.closer').click(function(e) {
   $(this).remove();
   $('p.expanded').removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed');
});
```

I'd also like to have a closing element appended when the paragraph is expanded so I can collapse it again. Check out my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3J2g7/

A few problems:

1.) Right now I simply don't get why the `a.closer` is appended whenever I click on the paragraph. It should only be appended once because I remove the class `collapsed` when clicking on it so it shouldn't fire the append() again, right?

2.) Any idea why the `a.closer` element does not get removed when clicking on it?

3.) Is there some fancy way to animate the entire experience. E.g. I'd simply love to slideDown() the rest of the paragraph when clicking on it and slideUp() again when clicking the closer.

*4.) The last thing I don't know is why I can't append three dots to the collapsed paragraph as a little hint so there is more text, I tried so using :after on the p, but doesn't work!*

Comment: You should ask ONE question at a time. not FOUR. hope my answer help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're changing the DOM so You have to use delegate event attach like `on`:

**Updated code:**

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'p.collapsed', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('collapsed').addClass('expanded')
               .hide().slideDown('fast');
        $(this).append("<a href='#' class='closer'>×</a>");
    });

    $('body').on('click', 'a.closer', function(e) {
        $(this).remove();
        $('p.expanded').slideUp('fast', function() {
             $(this).removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Instead of `body` give the selector the closest element that containts `p.collapsed` and `a.closer`.

> 3.) Is there some fancy way to animate the entire experience.

Yes, I used `hide` +`slideDown('fast')` and `slideUp('fast')` + `show` for better user experience.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/3J2g7/15/)**

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I just wonder if there is an easy way to have an animation on collapse as well? I'm trying right now, but can't seem to find an easy solution. Anyway, thank you, just perfect!

Comment: Yeah I saw that it's animating with slideDown, but doesn't animate when closing again, does it?

Comment: One could also shorten the `removeClass/addClass` code with: `$(this).toggleClass('collapsed expanded')` as long as one of the classes is predefined on the element.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.) Right now I simply don't get why the a.closer is appended whenever I click on the paragraph. It should only be appended once because I
>   remove the class collapsed when clicking on it so it shouldn't fire
>   the append() again, right?

This is because { $(this).append("×");} gets executed every time you click the close link .

Is there any particular reason you want to add and remove the link everytime you expand/collapse the div ? . Why don't Just add it on load OR BETTER add it into the html and let it be ?.

So your code would look like http://jsfiddle.net/azy777/EqDm9/10/

> 2.) Any idea why the a.closer element does not get removed when clicking on it?

Because you are adding an element dynamically so you need to bind the event using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

> 3.) Is there some fancy way to animate the entire experience. E.g. I'd simply love to slideDown() the rest of the paragraph when clicking on
>   it and slideUp() again when clicking the closer.

Yup, check out [animate](http://api.jquery.com/Animate/)

> 4.) The last thing I don't know is why I can't append three dots to the collapsed paragraph as a little hint so there is more text, I
>   tried so using :after on the p, but doesn't work!

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azy777/EqDm9/10/) , you need to add an extra element ( span used here ) and hide / show as required .

Hope this helps .